# Query String not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am new to Entity Framework Model. I am making a shopping cart like website where the user can select a category of products and then clicking on any one of the product category link, the next page displays the products in the corresponding category. I am using Entity Data Model and Query Strings. My code is as folloing:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EDS_ProductsByCategory" runat="server" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" 
                      ConnectionString="name=CommerceEntity"  
                      DefaultContainerName="CommerceEntity" 
                      EntitySetName="Products">
<WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CategoryId" QueryStringField="CatID" Type="String" />
       </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

The problems is that the page is displaying all the products irrespective of the product category. When the query string is categoryID=1 or categoryID=2, it displays the same list of products, i.e, all products. I followed the tutorial on http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/tailspin-spyworks/tailspin-spyworks-part-1 to achieve what I want. Please help me, I think I am making a small mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your QueryString CatId or CategoryId.

Comment: Thank you, I used these variables interchangeably at places due to confusion. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said CategoryId was the QueryString. But in your code you are using CatId as the QueryStringField. Change it to CategoryId and it should work.